# How to unpacking effectively Monte Carlo simulations in Python leveraging from numba? SOLVED

Tags: python, performance, simulation, numba

I am trying to create a Monte Carlo simulation effectivelly, because in my use case I would need to run this simulation 70*10^6 times. I was hoping that someone more experienced especially in performance could provide me some ideas of what could I try.
I have the following inputs:

- Demand

  - Each column is a product, Each row is a month
  - Some products in a determined month have a demand estimated by a triangular distribution tuple(min,mean,max). For those values I will make a Monte Carlo Simulation 1000 times
- Stock

My desired output is to find the:

- Median of the Distribution of the sum of available products (np.median(np.sum(available_products))), the median receives the 1000 simulations of the sum of available_products(available_products=stock-demand).

However I am having some issues:

- Speed, I have the intuition that there are clever ways to calculating leveraging vectorized functions. However I could not think of any, so I tried the usual loops. Please if you have any clue of any different approach that can be faster, let me know.
- FIXED Cannot set values to an array, in my solution I cannot set values using
  demand_j[index_demand_not_0][k] = dict_demand_values_simulations[k][j]

  - SOLUTION, I just need to access directly the demand_j location by demand_j[row,col].

Here is the code using the 3D array for demand as suggested by @Glauco:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit


@jit(nopython=True, nogil=True, fastmath=True)
def calc_triangular_dist(demand_distribution, num_monte):
    # Calculates triangular distributions
    return np.random.triangular(demand_distribution[0], demand_distribution[1], demand_distribution[2], size=num_monte)


def demand3d():
    # Goal find distribution_of_median_of_sum_available_products(np.median(np.sum(available_products)), the median from the 1000 Monte Carlo Simulations ): available_products=stock-demand (Each demand is generated by a Monte Carlo simulation 1000 times, therefore I will have 1000 demand arrays and consequently I will have a distribution of 1000 values of available products)
    # Input
    demand_triangular = np.array(
        [
            [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
            [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, (4.5, 5.5, 8.25)],
            [(2.1, 3.1, 4.65), 0.0, 0.0, (4.5, 5.5, 8.25)],
        ]
    )  # Each column represents a product, each row a month. Tuples are for triangular distribution (min,mean,max)
    stock = np.array(
        [[30, 30, 30, 22], [30, 30, 30, 22], [30, 30, 30, 22]]
    )  # Stock of available products, Each column represents a product, each row a month.
    num_sim_monte_carlo = 1000

    # Problem 1) How to unpack effectively each array of demand from simulation? Given that in my real case I would have 70 tuples to perform the Monte Carlo simulation?

    row, col = demand_triangular.shape
    index_demand_not_0 = np.where(
        demand_triangular != 0
    )  # Index of values that are not zeros,therefore my tuples for triangular distribution

    demand_j = np.zeros(shape=(row, col,num_sim_monte_carlo), dtype=float)

    triangular_len = len(demand_triangular[index_demand_not_0])  # Length of rows to calculate triangular
    for k in range(0, triangular_len):  # loop per values to simulate
        demand_j[index_demand_not_0[0][k], index_demand_not_0[1][k]] = calc_triangular_dist(
            demand_triangular[index_demand_not_0][k], num_sim_monte_carlo
        )

    sums_available_simulations = np.zeros(
        shape=num_sim_monte_carlo
    )  # Stores each 1000 different sums of available, generated by unpacking the dict_demand_velues_simulations

    for j in range(0, num_sim_monte_carlo):  # loop per number of monte carlo simulations
        available = stock - demand_j[:,:,j]
        available[available < 0] = 0  # Fixes with values are negative
        sums_available_simulations[j] = np.sum(available)  # Stores available for each simulation
    print("Median of distribution of available is: ", np.median(sums_available_simulations))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demand3d()
```

The results of the suggestions show a much better performance using the 3D array :), now that I have only arrays I can try to to improve further using numba.

```
Baseline  0.4067141000000001
1) Monte Carlo per loop  0.035586100000000176
2) Demand 3D  0.017964299999999822
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

internal loop can be removed using array programming + fancy indexing, this speed up the assignment to demand_j.
Another point is that you can generate one time the demand_j adding a dimension (the num_sim_montecarlo) it become 3d array, and in the loop you must only read the values avoiding to create values at each loop.

Comment: Thanks @Glauco you gave me valuable insights! Regarding the suggestion, 1) Given the dict_demand_values_simulations I did not found a way to use numpy indexing, but to cut one loop I tested instead of running the MonteCarlo one by one instead of loop.  2) Tested addying a dimension(num_sim_montecarlo) to the demand_j. It improved a lot the performance. Many thanks